# Bending image effect with CSS/JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style the images on my website with a slight bending-effect and a shadow below the bended parts of the image - just like this (seen on ebay):

[image]

Does somebody know how to achieve? Any suggested jQuery or java-script libraries? Or is it achieveable with CSS only?

Comment: The image you posted a picture of isn't bent. The effect comes from the shadow, which can be added as a (background) image.

Comment: oh you're right, it's just a amazing visual effect... ;-)

Comment: ... the images I use are of different size. but I will try to add the white border with css and the shadow as a background image relatively positioned to the left-lower corner.

Comment: Tried to make one with CSS3 (modified from slash197's answer), but the shadow was derping a bit. Someone can fix it if they can. http://jsfiddle.net/BH3eq/2/

Comment: thanks pietu1998, this is fair enough for me :-)

Comment: I managed to do it, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a modification to slash197's answer. It looks exactly like in the picture, at least in Firefox. However it is ridiculously large and needs additional markup.

I put the image container div (most of code by slash197) inside another div. Then I added yet another div and gave it a shadow, then I just positioned it correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="shadow">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://your.server.com/path/to/your/image.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* or block */
    margin: 20px; /* not required */
}
.img-container {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 5px 5px #cccccc; /* adjust color, blur or spread if you want */
    transform: skewy(-3deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    bottom: 22px; /* adjust this to change the shadow's size */
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here it is in all its glory: http://jsfiddle.net/VCEJB/1/

**EDIT:** Changed `rotate` to `skewy` as it probably looks marginally better.

Comment: wow looks great on firefox! thanks a lot pietu!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with CSS only: put the image in a container, style that container with a padding, border, border radius and box shadow.

The box shadow will give you a different shadow than the one in your example but it might be enough for you so you won't need external libraries. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/k7Kpv/2/

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 12px -3px #cccccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I meant. the shadow created by your suggested code generates a uniform drop-shadow on two sides of the image, but I need only a shadow on the corner in order to have this "bending-illusion"...

Comment: slash197, thanks for the sample!