# CSS bend image and add shadow

Tags: html, css

I have an image and want to display it like this:

- Add border.
- Bend it.
- Add shadow.

The attached image shows exactly how it should look (*white rectangle contains the original image*).

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21316531/2105988) but I don't have the CSS skills to archive all three requirements. (*got stuck with shadow direction and bending*)

[image]

Comment: You can not do this shadow with pure css!

Comment: Have a look at this http://cssdeck.com/labs/page-curl-box-shadow

Comment: @jiff why not this shadow in particular? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
<div class="box effect">
    <h3>Effect</h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    background:#E8C300;
    margin:40px auto;

}


.effect
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect:before, .effect:after
{
      z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 300px;
    background: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0);
    box-shadow: -14px -1px 7px #777;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.effect:after
{
     transform: rotate(-5deg);
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/84me6p6b/2

Comment: +1 thanks! that's something to work with. I will work on top of your answer and see if I can get a gradient for the shadow. Also your shadow is rectangular and not triangular, maybe that's what @Darren Sweeney meant with his comment